# @model on my Razor page doesn't work

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to get my razor page to run but I keep getting this error:

ASP._Page_Views_profile_add_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override

and in doing some research I have found out that I needed to add some things to the web.config which I have done but also that I need to add the "@model" to the top and provide a model. So far I have this:

```
@model ProfileViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Master.cshtml";
}
```

the `@model` keyword does not work, its not highlighted yellow like the `@inherits` keyword would be, I believe that is my problem but no clue on how to fix it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@model` keyword won't be highlighted in yellow in the Visual Studio designer. It needs to point to a valid class so that if you put the cursor over it and press <kbd>F12</kbd> you should navigate to the corresponding class definition. If this doesn't happen you might need to specify the full type name including the namespace.

Also the controller action that is rendering this particular view needs to pass an instance of the model:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ProfileViewModel model = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Now it gives me this error: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation, which puts me back to where I was..do you know what I do from here?

Comment: @efleming, I think that your view is not strongly typed. You will get such kind of exceptions in this case. Are you sure that the model you specified exists and that the controller action is correctly passing an instance of this very same model to the view?

Comment: The model exists and I am passing an instance of that model to the view..the reason the highlighting caught me was because in the MvcMusicStore the @model and @inherits are both highlighted...where mine is not, it gives me no itellisense for anything..

Comment: @efleming, does it work if you create a new project using the default template and simply add a model to the `Index` action?

Comment: Yes, and I even just used a MVC update tool, and now my @model is being highlighted but is throwing the same error at the end..

Comment: Okay, I guess it is "working" now. Can you not use a Layout when using a @model? Whenever I comment out the line -- Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Master.cshtml"; -- Then it works but there are no styles on the page. How do I use both?

Comment: @efleming, maybe the problem was in your layout? You had some code on the layout that was throwing the exception? The fact that it works when you remove it is a strong indication that this might be the case.

Comment: Yep, the problem was in the layout, but I still needed to do all the steps you said previously. Thank you!