# BC30561: 'Html' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web.WebPages, System.Web.Mvc'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I upgraded my MVC application from MVC 3 to 5.2.2 and now I'm getting this error. I've made a brand new MVC project using the new project wizard and this works, and I've compared my `/web.config` and `Views/web.config` files across the two projects and don't see any differences that seem important.

Looking in the object browser, I see that there are in fact two different `HtmlHelper` objects defined in `System.Web.WebPages` and `System.Web.Mvc`, which seems relevant:

[image]

But I'm not sure what to do with this fact.

Answer (score 7):

After wrestling with this for hours and then posting the question here, I figured it out a minute later; I had specified a strongly typed model like this:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of MyModel)
```

But around the same time that I upgraded to 5.2.2, I reorganized my namespaces so that `MyModel` was in a different namespace, and this caused the problem. The fix was to change it to this:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of NewNamespace.MyModel)
```

It would be nice if the compiler had caught this. It would never have occurred to me that it couldn't find my model object type **at all** but wouldn't just say so.

Comment: You are not alone. I did the same silly thing and got the same error. You just saved me those hours =)

Comment: Glad to hear that all that pain was not in vain then. :-)

Comment: +1.  I had to re-enable some old controller code which was deactivated over a year ago.  Had this exact error message show up, and sure enough - namespaces had been changed between deactivation and reactivation of the code!  This saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your [`model` points to a real class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4961774/1366033), but this is probably because the [`MvcWebPageRazorHost` isn't registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5637743/1366033) or [different versions are registered in the root web.config vs. the views web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34804827/1366033), often caused by [updating MVC versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360259/1366033)

I was getting several compiler errors anytime I opened a Razor View:

```
Type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage' is not defined.
'Context' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
sub 'Execute' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class.
'Html' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web.WebPages, System.Web.Mvc'.
```

What fixed it was updating the `webpages:Version` in the web.config:

**From This**:

```xml
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
```

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**To This**:

```xml
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```